# A Configuration Change was Requested to Clear TPM and keyboard and mouse are not working

Tags: windows-10, tpm

When you reset your computer to the factory. it will take several minutes to clear all the data after that there will be a pop up A Configuration Change was Requested to Clear TPM with options as Yes and No, in My case my keyboard that is on my laptop was not working from the start and I didn't think before resetting the computer about that. so now I am stuck at this blue window and question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For My problem, I connected an external keyboard but that was not working along with my Bluetooth one. the trick was to click the power button of the laptop for serval minutes which will give a satisfying shutting-off sound after that connect your wired keyboard and start the laptop normally now you can use your wired keyboard. took me hours to figure that out.